# Find all files modified in a specific ClearCase branch?

Tags: clearcase

Is there a way I can create a view that will give me a snapshot of all the files modified in a specific ClearCase branch?

For example, say I have two branches:

```
product_1.0_dev
product_migration_1.0_dev
```

The second branch is conceived as a testing ground for upgrading our core framework dependencies.  I know that if I modify a file in product_migration_1.0_dev, then I will have a \1 version under this branch, so there has to be a way to write a load rule to get this info easily into a snapshot.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited my answer to propose a config spec that should list the files you want. And only those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a selection rule (not a load rule)

```
 element * .../product_migration_1.0_dev/LATEST
 element * .../product_1.0_dev/LATEST
 element * /main/LATEST
```

Note the '`...`' notation (see [version selector](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/version_selector.htm)), an ellipsis wildcard which allows to select a branch at any branch level.

Note that would list *all* files, including the ones you want.

If you want to *see* only the files for a particular branch, you still need to select their *parent* directories: and those might not have a version in the `product_migration_1.0_dev` branch.

So the following config spec (that I invite you to test in a *dynamic* view first: it is quicker, then you will report that config spec in a snapshot view, with its own *load* rules) would be more precise:

```
 element * .../product_migration_1.0_dev/LATEST
 element -directory * .../product_1.0_dev/LATEST
 element -directory * /main/LATEST
```

So you would select files and directories having a LATEST in `product_migration_1.0_dev` branch.
Otherwise, you select directories only in `product_1.0_dev` branch or in `main` branch.

That way, you are sure to select the parent directory of an element which might have a version in `product_migration_1.0_dev` branch.
If you don't do that, your view won't ever be able to select the files, because their parent directories are not accessible (none of their versions is selected from which a `product_migration_1.0_dev` branch starts).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in marking this as Correct.  Your second solution is EXACTLY what I wanted and a HUGE timesaver.  Thanks again, ClearCase Wizard.