# Details of config spec in base ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

My base ClearCase config spec reads like this:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../Branch_F13R2/LATEST
```

All is good, but I am wondering what is the `.../` doing at the beginning of the path? In UCM, we can see the streams and VOBS in Clear Case explorer, but in base ClearCase, how to know that if I want to check out from `Branch_F13R2`, I need `.../` at the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you don't know the parent branch.

`.../` in a selection rule allows for ClearCase to select that branch, from whatever branch it comes from: `/main`, or any other branch.
To see more about that notation, called **ellipsis wildcard**, see "[Find all files modified in a specific ClearCase branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920442/find-all-files-modified-in-a-specific-clearcase-branch/13920707#13920707)".

I would also recommend to add the rule

```
element * /main/LATEST
```

Not every parent directory has a version in the branch you are looking for, and without this last selection rule, it would have nothing to select, making any sub element inaccessible.